# Creating editable table from multiple sql database tables in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I have a problem with displaying and editing some data from database to ASP.Net webpage.

Data from database consist from few different tables:

Table **Files**, witch contains file_id and a file name

```
|  file_id   |   file_name |
--------------------------
|    GUID    |   VARCHAR   |
```

file is saved in database as a collection of lines for one file_id,

Table **Items**,witch contains basically all the lines from all the files

```
| item_id    | file_id     | step        | number |
---------------------------------------------------
|    GUID    |   VARCHAR   |  BIGINT     | BIGINT |
```

Table **Wording**, witch contains all distinctive wording

```
| wording_id | wording_eng | description |
-----------------------------------------
|    GUID    |   VARCHAR   |  VARCHAR    |
```

And **M_N_table** witch contains connection between items and wording

```
| item_id    | wording_id  |
----------------------------
|    GUID    |   GUID      |
```

my final display table should look like this and should be editable

```
|           |     file1     |     file2     |     file3     |.........|      fileN    |             |            |
| sortorder --------------------------------------------------------------------------| wording_eng | desription |
|           | step | number | step | number | step | number |.........| step | number |             |            |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1       | 10   |  15    |      |        |       |       |.........|       |       | something1  | something2 |           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   2       |      |        |      |        |  25   |  15   |.........|    5  |  17   | something3  | something4 |          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   3       |   2  | 4      |  5   |  16    |   17  |   3   |.........|    1  |  15   | something5  | something6 |
```

So for every file from some selected list,witch means variable number of files, I need to read all the wordings and if a wording is connected to item in M_N_table and that item exist in selected files I have to write value of **step** and **number** to that files column as shown, if they don't exist it will be written blank value.

Problem I'm having is creating Table or DataList or GridView where I can have connection to **item_id** and **wording_id** when I'm editing data. I managed to create "pivot" datatable in C# in backcode, using all of these tables and created gridview with dynamic number of columns but problem is I don't have information about what item_id I'm actually editing it just goes back to changing value in datatable.

What is the best way to display this data? I tried making dynamic pivot table in SQL to display it directly with gridview but without aggregation it's impossible,so I had to do it with datatable's in C# back-code. And how can I make it so that when I edit data in displayed table I get the same changes in database?

Comment: View with INSTEAD OF trigger.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand,I'm not so good with SQL, how should I use INSTEAD OF triggers to solve my problem?